# Concatenate columns at the end of a MultiIndex columns DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `DataFrames` `df` :

```
df = 
kind                            A               B
names          u1      u2      u3      y1      y2
Time
0.0        0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.7373  0.1387
0.1        0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.8421  0.2670
0.2        0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.8060  0.0040
0.3        0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.0771  0.1023
0.4        0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.9800  0.0715
```

and `df1`:

```
df1 = 
kind            A      
names      potato        
Time
0.0        0.4043  
0.1        0.9801 
0.2        0.1298  
0.3        0.9564  
0.4        0.4409
```

I want to concatenate the two `DataFrames` such that the resulting `DataFrame` is:

```
df2 = 
kind                                    A               B
names          u1      u2      u3  potato      y1      y2
Time
0.0        0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.5083  0.7373  0.1387
0.1        0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.6748  0.8421  0.2670
0.2        0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.1753  0.8060  0.0040
0.3        0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.5953  0.0771  0.1023
0.4        0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.4409  0.9800  0.0715
```

What I run is `pandas.concat([df1, df2, axis=1).sort_index(level="kind", axis=1)` but that results in

```
kind                                    A               B
names      potato      u1      u2      u3      y1      y2
Time
0.0        0.4043  0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.7373  0.1387
0.1        0.9801  0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.8421  0.2670
0.2        0.1298  0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.8060  0.0040
0.3        0.9564  0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.0771  0.1023
0.4        0.4409  0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.9800  0.0715
```

i.e. the column `potato` is appended at the beginning of `df["A"]` whereas I want it appended to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `sort_remaining=False` in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(level="kind", axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
print (df)
kind        A                               B        
names      u1      u2      u3  potato      y1      y2
Time                                                 
0.0    0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.4043  0.7373  0.1387
0.1    0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.9801  0.8421  0.2670
0.2    0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.1298  0.8060  0.0040
0.3    0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.9564  0.0771  0.1023
0.4    0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.4409  0.9800  0.0715
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to this problem, one safer than the other. Both rely on the use of the `df.insert` paradigm, however the 1st one is simple and dangerous, while the second one slightly more complicated, but allows for more "security".

## Solution 1

You can simply use the `df.insert` command, which allows to insert a column at a specified index. In your case, that would mean:

```py
df.insert(loc=3, column=df1.columns[0], value=df1.values)
```

Which gives the desired output:

```bash
kind    A   B
names   u1  u2  u3  Potato  y1  y2
Time                        
0.0 0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.4043  0.7373  0.1387
0.1 0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.9801  0.8421  0.2670
0.2 0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.1298  0.8060  0.0040
0.3 0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.9564  0.0771  0.1023
0.4 0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.4409  0.9800  0.0715
```

However, it is not really a merge, and could easily give exceptions. For example, if df1 has a different length, it will give an Exception of the type (in the example has 1 less value).

```bash
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (5)
```

This merging is also not performed with respect to the index, i.e., the index of `df1` is completely ignored in the merging.

I would suggest to use this only if your are certain of the type of data your are merging.

## Solution 2

First performing a concatenate and then an insert allows to account for different indexes.
This can be done like this:

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
colname: tuple = ('A', 'Potato')
colvalue: pd.Series = df2[colname]
df2.pop(colname)
df2.insert(loc=3, column=colname, value=colvalue)
```

Indeed, if `df1` has a different index, this method allows to account for that.

## Example

In order to explain the difference in the two solutions, let us consider the case in which `df` and `df1` have different indexes.
That is:

```py
display(df)
```

```bash
kind    A   B
names   u1  u2  u3  y1  y2
Time                    
0.0 0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.7373  0.1387
0.1 0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.8421  0.2670
0.2 0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.8060  0.0040
0.3 0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.0771  0.1023
0.4 0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.9800  0.0715
```

and

```py
display(df1)
```

```bash
kind    A
names   Potato
0.0 0.4043
0.1 0.9801
0.2 0.1298
0.3 0.9564
0.5 0.4409
```

In this scenario, **Solution 1** will lead to the following merge:

```py
df.insert(loc=3, column=df1.columns[0], value=df1.values)
display(df)
```

```bash
kind    A   B
names   u1  u2  u3  Potato  y1  y2
Time                        
0.0 0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.4043  0.7373  0.1387
0.1 0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.9801  0.8421  0.2670
0.2 0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.1298  0.8060  0.0040
0.3 0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.9564  0.0771  0.1023
0.4 0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  0.4409  0.9800  0.0715
```

which would be *wrong*. **Solution 2**, however, would lead to the correct output:

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
colname: tuple = ('A', 'Potato')
colvalue: pd.Series = df2[colname]
df2.pop(colname)
df2.insert(loc=3, column=colname, value=colvalue)
display(df2)
```

```bash
kind    A   B
names   u1  u2  u3  Potato  y1  y2
0.0 0.5083  0.1007  0.8001  0.4043  0.7373  0.1387
0.1 0.6748  0.0354  0.0076  0.9801  0.8421  0.2670
0.2 0.1753  0.1013  0.5231  0.1298  0.8060  0.0040
0.3 0.5953  0.6505  0.7127  0.9564  0.0771  0.1023
0.4 0.4409  0.0193  0.6765  NaN 0.9800  0.0715
0.5 NaN NaN NaN 0.4409  NaN NaN
```

### Recap best solution

Use `concat` and then use `pop` and `insert` the new column. If in a hurry, and sure of what you're doing, you can go ahead and use just `insert, but *be careful*.

Comment: Or use [jezreal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74301560/11509190)'s answer, which is way more elegant,